# R Create new variable/column based on subsequent observations

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

Given a dataframe:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    record_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
    day_count = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
    change = c(0,2,0,1,0,2,0,1,2,0)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

with:
`change (0)` = no change, `change (1)` = start/resume,  and `change(2)` = stop.

I want to create a new column, which evaluates whether the stop was the last stop (i.e. does a change(1) occur in the sequence following the stop)

Expected output

```
df_output <- structure(
  list(
    record_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
    day_count = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
    change = c(0,2,0,1,0,2,0,1,2,0),
    last_stop = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I believe I have to slice the subsequent observations after a stop and create a vector out of it. Then evaluate whether a (1) occurred in the vector. If so, then it was not the last stop, if not, then it was the final stop.

The problem is that I do not know how to do this repeatedly for every 2 that occur....

Hope you can help

BW

Comment: Your expected output is missing your output variable.

Comment: thank you, corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with Base R. It works for every `record_id`, since I suppose that's your goal.

I've expanded your data to have:

- `record_id == 1` that ends with a `1`,
- `record_id == 2` that ends with a `2`,
- `record_id == 3` that composed only by zeros.

```
df <- structure(
 list(
  record_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), 
  day_count = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), 
  change = c(0,2,0,1,0,2,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0)), 
 row.names = c(NA, -15L),
 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here's the solution:

```
df$last_stop <- ave(df$change, 
                    df$record_id, 
                    FUN = function(x){
                     
                     l <- numeric(length(x))
                     i <- Position(function(x) x!=0, x, right = TRUE)
                     if(identical(x[i], 2)) l[i] <- 1
                     l
                     
                     })
df

#>    record_id day_count change last_stop
#> 1          1         1      0         0
#> 2          1         2      2         0
#> 3          1         3      0         0
#> 4          1         4      1         0
#> 5          1         5      0         0
#> 6          2         1      2         0
#> 7          2         2      0         0
#> 8          2         3      1         0
#> 9          2         4      2         1
#> 10         2         5      0         0
#> 11         3         1      0         0
#> 12         3         2      0         0
#> 13         3         3      0         0
#> 14         3         4      0         0
#> 15         3         5      0         0
```

Notice that you have a 1 in `last_stop` only for `record_id == 2` at row 9.

`ave` is an interesting function that splits `df$change` by `df$record_id` and applies the function to each component.

The function:

- creates a vector of zeros (which is gonna be your `df$last_stop`)
- looks for the `Position` of first non-zero value from the right (or the bottom)
- if that value is 2, then it adds a 1 into the output vector, otherwise a vector of zeros is returned.

Comment: Dear Edo. Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed, I want it to work for multiple record_id's. However, as Onyambu below has suggested, it does not work if a 1 occurred after the 2, without having a 2 afterwards. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code should work.

```
df$last_stop = sapply(
   1:length(df$change),
   function(i){
     ifelse(df$change[i] != 2, 0,
            as.numeric(!any(df$change[i:length(df$change)] == 1)))
   })
```

The sapply function iters over you df$change vector,output 0 if change is different than 2 otherwise tests if there is any 1 in the remaining elements, if there is none the condition returns TRUE that is then converted to numeric since as.numeric(TRUE) == 1.

Comment: Thank you Wawv. This works fine indeed in the sample I have provided. As edo has suggested down below, I want this code to work for every record_id.

Image a record_id number 2, with exact the same numbers as number 1. I tried the following in a dataframe with record_id 1 and 2,  which does not work: 

```df2 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  mutate(last_stop = sapply(
    1:length(df2$change),
   function(i){
     ifelse(df2$change[i] != 2, 0,
            as.numeric(!any(df2$change[i:length(df2$change)] == 1)))
   }
   )) ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It should work if you delete the "df2$" from the function so it only refers to the variable change within the group (and not within the data.frame).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the codes provided do not take into consideration that you might have a 1  after the 2 without having a 2 afterwards. To take this into consideration, we could do:

```
a <- max(which(df$change==2))
b <- max(which(df$change==1))
df$change <- numeric(nrow(df))
df$change [if(a>b) a else 0] <- 1
df
```

Comment: Hi Onyambu, Thank you for your help. This works indeed fine for the example I have provided. As i forgot to mention, I have multiple record_id's. What would your suggestion be? BW and thanks in advance